# How to reach int variable that inside my controller method when i write unit test with xUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, xunit

I am trying to write unit test for my controller. I am using xUnit to test my methots.

I can reach "changePasswordX" method inside my controller to test but i can not reach to my userId variable and claim value to check are they equal or not ?

How can i test this code in xUnit?

```
    [HttpGet("ChangePassword")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ChangePassword(int userId, oldPassword, newPassword)
    {      
        if (userId != int.Parse(User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value))
            return Unauthorized();

         _repo.changePasswordX(userId, oldPassword, newPassword);

        return Ok();
    }
```

Comment: What in the world do you mean by "I can reach all methots inside my voids"?

Comment: For example if i write a inside my method this way :
_repo.changePasswor("oldPassword","newPassword");
I can reach that changePassword method and can test it.

Comment: I'm sorry you're not making any sense.  I don't understand at all what you're saying with this question.

Comment: I am sorry. I am editting my question

Comment: What does your test look like? Are you having issues with the `async` or the `User` dependency?

Comment: @LennartStoop no i dont have problem about async but the point is i dont know how can i write test for this code

Comment: @rory.ap Is it more make sense right now ?

Comment: You cannot test any code. You have to take care that your code is testable. This method is not testable, because of that hardcoded dependency with static User class (or is it a property)

Comment: @SirRufo: `User` is an property on `Controller`, which pulls from the injected `HttpContext` instance. It's something you'd need to mock, but it's perfectly testable.

Comment: So basically the question is: how do I mock `User` ?

Comment: @LennartStoop Actually in this case yes... But after i read the answer of Chris I am convinced that i just need to test to  return Unauthorized. Oh God i am sooooo new at writing unit test.... pls forgive my misktakes

Answer (score 1):

Unit testing does not test every *intermediate* result of every step of a method.

Unit testing is meant to test the overall output or return value of a method, given certain inputs.

If you need to test that single line of code, then put it in a separate location (library) where it can be called *and* tested.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you're actually trying to achieve, but this is the wrong way to be writing unit/integration tests, regardless. You don't and shouldn't test the value of `userId` versus the claim yourself in your unit test. You know that if it doesn't match, your action returns and an `UnauthorizedResult`, whereas if it matches, you'll get an `OkResult`. If you're unit testing, you simply stub out your user principal, call the action as a method, and verify the return. If you're integration testing, the procedures mostly the same: you authorize the call, and verify that the status code is either 401 or 200, depending on which case you're testing.

Comment: Thank you Chirs for your answer. Actually the thing that i am trying to do is testing return Unauthorized();

I have written one test for ok result. And it worked perfectly but to test return nauthorized, i thought that i first i need to test userId and the other element. That s why i asked my question this way.

Comment: It's all about your mocks. To test the Unauthorized path, you simply set up a mock where the ids won't match, just as you had to set up a mock to make the ids match for the OK path.